# Why does TCP wait for three duplicate ACK before fast retransmit?

Tags: tcp, network-programming

Why does TCP wait for three duplicate ACK before fast retransmit?

Answer (score 70, accepted):

[RFC 2001](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc2001.html) says

> Since TCP does not know whether a duplicate ACK is caused by a lost
>      segment or just a reordering of segments, it waits for a small number
>      of duplicate ACKs to be received.  It is assumed that if there is
>      just a reordering of the segments, there will be only one or two
>      duplicate ACKs before the reordered segment is processed, which will
>      then generate a new ACK.  If three or more duplicate ACKs are
>      received in a row, it is a strong indication that a segment has been
>      lost.  TCP then performs a retransmission of what appears to be the
>      missing segment, without waiting for a retransmission timer to
>      expire.

The reasoning for not doing the retransmit until the third duplicate seems to be that until that point it's more likely to just be out-of-order delivery and the retransmit isn't really needed.